# Find sibling/parent of a span tag with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

This is my first question so if I missed some information or did anything wrong I already apologize for that.
I am using a ChromeDriver to scrape through the Internet. The used language is Python in combination with Selenium.

I have an element which is a span tag that I stored in a variable called *elem*. I could find the parent element of *elem*

```
articles.append(elem.find_parent("a")['href'])
```

which was stored in that array *articles*.
Now I need to find the ancestor element which is the span tag with the class saying "price": [lowest line represents *elem* and the second line is the element I am looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag0Jq.png)

However, trying the same like before:

```
elem.find_parent("span")['class']
```

doesn't work out for me and I get a Nonetype Error. I have tried multiple other methods but always got a NoneType Error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Parent element

Parent selects the parent of the current node.

Lets take as an example the reputation `span` element from Stackoverflow user's profile:
To go one level up with **XPATH**:

`//span[@class='grid--cell ']`

#### Solution 1

You can go one level up with `/..`

```
//span[@class='grid--cell ']/..
```

#### Solution 2

Using XPATH `parent` :

```
//span[@class='grid--cell ']/parent::div[@class='grid gs8 fs-headline1']
```

`parent` selects the parent of the current node

#### Solution 3

Using XPATH `ancestor`

```
//span[@class='grid--cell ']/ancestor::div[@class='grid gs8 fs-headline1']
```

The difference is that `ancestor` selects not only the parent, but also grandparents and so on of the current element.

There is no a good way currently to do the same with CSS.

To find **child** elements I usually use `//` for all siblings or `/` for a direct sibling.

Comment: I'm gonna show you a little trick to select a Parent tag that contains a span class. //div[@class='grid gs8 fs-headline1'][.//span[@class='grid--cell ']].

Comment: I dont have access to the xpath, I am using beautiful soup and have every element in an array. Now I want to go to each element and find that specific parent tag. I dont have the xpatht though.

Comment: There is still probably no way to do this with css selectors. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 3):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="
C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/about_careers.htm")
#identify child element
l= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='heading']")
#identify parent from child element with (..) in xpath
t= l.find_element_by_xpath("..")
# get_attribute() method to obtain class of parent
print("Parent class attribute: " + t.get_attribute("class"))
driver.close()
```

Solution from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-find-parent-elements-by-python-webdriver